# Scala: How to make a closure not to see changes in its free variable?

Tags: scala

In the following code snippet, closure `foo` see the changes made in `x` as it should in scala. However, how can I make local variable `y` in `foo` hold value of x permanently and not see changes?

```
scala> var x = 10
x: Int = 10

scala> val foo = (a:Int) => {val y = x; a + y}
foo: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> foo(3)
res1: Int = 13

scala> x = 5
x: Int = 5

scala> foo(3)    //see changes made in x. But how can I make closure not to see changes made on x?
res2: Int = 8
```

Comment: Easy. Don't use vars.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
val foo = ((x:Int) => (a:Int) => {val y = x; a + y})(x)
```

In this case, x is bound in foo.

What you are doing is an example of [closure](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_closures.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```scala
scala> var x = 10
x: Int = 10

scala> val foo = { val y = x; (a: Int) => a + y }
foo: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1027/1344946518@5416f8db

scala> foo(3)
res0: Int = 13

scala> x = 5
x: Int = 5

scala> foo(3)
res1: Int = 13
```